# Hiding transform panel from 3D view properties 'UI' Panel from user?

Tags: python, 3d-view

Almost everything is in the question. I've been browsing the web for a while and couldn't find out a way to hide or at least disable the Properties `Transform Panel` of the 'View_3D' area. Is there a way to redraw (override the draw) entirely this Panel, by the way? I need the user to be unable to transform the objects otherwise, but by using my custom tools. I've been able to remove every other Panel but this one. Any brilliant idea?

Also, is there a way to simply remove this whole area (and replace it by a new fresh one), or even better redraw completely the area?

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: Absolutely, I finally left this panel accessible, and spend my time to develop my application. But in the end, I'll need do it. So I'll be very thankful if you can help with this. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to draw is somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

I use this to draw it in the tool shelve

```
class ObjectTransformation(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Transformation"
    bl_idname = "Transformation"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modeling Toolbox"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.column().prop(obj, "location")
        row.column().prop(obj, "rotation_euler", text="Rotation")
        row.column().prop(obj, "scale")
        row = layout.row()
        #Calls the CTRL A menu
        #row.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Apply Tans").name="VIEW3D_MT_object_apply"
        row.operator("object.transform_apply", text="Apply Rot").rotation=True
        row.operator("object.transform_apply", text="Apply Scale").scale=True
        row = layout.row()
        row.column().prop(obj, "dimensions")
```

Comment: OK, thanks for sharing. I might be missing something, but drawing another Transform Panel in the Toolshelves region, won't make it disappear from the Properties region. I don't really see what part of my question you are answering here. I think we misunderstood each other, or my question was unclear, but my point was: How do I hide the default Transform Panel?

Comment: To my understanding the trans tap in properties panel is hard coded and not scripted. I looked into space_view3d.py and did not see it being mentioned.

Comment: Yep. As far as I have been digging there was no other way than changing (a few) things in a couple of `C` files and recompile Blender. But I was hopping some pythonic trick could help with overriding/redrawing the content of the whole Property region. Thanks anyway. Cheers.

Comment: I also looked at space_view3d.py and didn't find anything about transforms. However, for the future, if you want to remove a panel, you just need to unregister the class it's associated with. For example, Name Panel addon replaces the default name panel in properties region, then registers its own panel. You can see that code here: https://github.com/trentinfrederick/name-panel/blob/master/__init__.py#L121 - Transform and View panels are the only ones I can't find info for, so they likely link to much deeper data in blender.

Comment: @Gauthier Boaglio, would you mind to share what C files you have changed? I'm at the same problem at the moment.

Comment: Have it. It's the class view3d_panel_transform in the view3d_buttons.c File. Line 1137 bis 1172. Plus line 1182. pt->draw = view3d_panel_transform; . And there are of course some more classes called from the class view3d_panel_transform class. Which you might want to delete too. 

But it's enough to turn off the class view3d_panel_transform to hide the panel from the Properties sidebar. This class can by the way not be accessed by Python. And so not be unregistered. Original comment from the c file:  /* XXX C panels not  available through RNA (bpy.types)! */